# <br> element not working after re-ordering div order

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery's `.sortable` function to allow the user to drag and drop a `<div>` to reorder it. Above each `<div>` is a `<br>` which adds a space above it.

However, after re-ordering a `<div>`, the `<br>` stops working - the space is "missing".

*JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Ln5zzvh/*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sortable').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
  });
});
```

```css
div#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable">
  <br>
  <div id="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
</div>
```

Before re-ordering:

[image]

After re-ordering:

[image]

Comment: why not using margin instead of <br>?

Comment: and uses classes not identical id's!

Comment: use margin bottom 10px instead of br

Comment: I could do this, but is this, but is there an explanation as to why the `<br>` doesn't work after re-ordering?

Comment: because the jquery-ui regenerates the html divs and i think removes br

Comment: you're only dragging the div's not the br's

Comment: The `<br>` does work. It's just that you are reordering the `<div>`'s and not the `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `<br>` tag for that purpose. Use margins instead. Also make sure you don't use id's more than once as they should be unique!

However the problem occurs because you are only ordering the divs and not the br tags. So the br tags end up at the end or at the top (based on what div you drag).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sortable').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
  });
});
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Selects every div.container that are preceded by a div.container element */
div.container ~ div.container {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable">
  <div class="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    helloooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `margin` instead of `<br>` [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Ln5zzvh/1/)